# Crash when converting String to Int Android

Tags: java, android, string, int

First I am really sorry if there is already an answer out there but I have tried them and they do not work.
I am converting a `EditText` to an `int` then adding `1` and displaying it. I know that it is the conversion which is causing the app to crash because I have tried displaying it just as a `String` without changing it and it works fine and the `EditText` has the number attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText age;
        Button accept;
        final TextView ageTest;
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageEdit);
        accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ageTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ageTest);
        accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int ageInt = Integer.valueOf(age.getText().toString());
                ageInt++;
                ageTest.setText(ageInt);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the wrong `setText` method, and hence your code probably throws a `ResourceNotFoundException`

Use the [`setText(CharSequence text)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, i.e convert your `int` to `String` :

`ageTest.setText(String.valueOf(ageInt));`

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that a TextView could only accept strings!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

`String strI = Integer.toString(i);`

to your onClick function, and change `ageTest.setText(ageInt);` to `ageTest.setText(strI);`